# JSP is not showing in eclipse wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am unable to find the JSP page in Eclipse while creating a new project even when I have added the web dependency.

Can anyone help me how can I use the JSP pages for my program?

I don't know whether the problem is with the dependencies or with the new Eclipse version.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new Dynamic Web project in eclipse, You need to create a JSP file in your desired folder like **WebContent**, **WEB-INF** etc where you want to keep your JSP page, or even you can create a folder named **"jsp"** and put all JSP files inside that folder.

You can do this by selecting the project location and clicking on

```
New -> File -> Give the filename (ex : login.jsp) -> enter.
```

This will create a JSP file for you.

Attaching snapshot for "Dynamic Web Project"

[image]

Attaching snapshot for creating new JSP file in Eclipse :

[image]

Comment: There is no option in my eclipse as Dynamic Web project. I have downloaded the latest version of eclipse.

Comment: @SasiDhar : It must be there. Try searching. I have added snapshots for you to find where it is., Also ensure that you have downloaded Eclipse for Java EE.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use(download) Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. Then create create a new project of type Dynamic Web Project in eclipse.  Then Add file (new->file) of type JSP on that project in webcontent folder.

Answer (score 2):

1. Help/Install new Software
2. Add repository (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars) if not available.
3. Under (Web,XML,Java, EE and OSGI Enterprise Development)
4. Select: Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
5. Select: Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
6. Select: Eclipse Web Developer Tools
7. Restart Eclipse.